SimpleXML Attributes Inconsistent
I have the below XML in an external file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<propertyList date="2024-08-27-10:09:55">
  <residential modTime="2024-08-27-10:01:59" status="current">
    <uniqueID>1P0100</uniqueID>
    <authority value="auction"/>
    <price display="yes">6000000</price>
    <landDetails>
      <area unit="hectare">5.09</area>
      <frontage unit="meter">0</frontage>
    </landDetails>
    <address display="yes" streetview="yes">
      <streetNumber>123</streetNumber>
      <street>Smith St</street>
      <suburb display="yes">My Suburb</suburb>
      <state>My State</state>
      <postcode>1234</postcode>
    </address>
    <category name="House"/>
  </residential>
</propertyList>

I am using simplexml_load_file as follows:
$xml = simplexml_load_file("properties.xml");
$residential = $xml->residential;
print_r($residential);

The above outputs this object:
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [modTime] => 2024-08-27-10:01:59
            [status] => current
        )
    [uniqueID] => 1P0100
    [authority] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [value] => auction
                )

        )
    [price] => 6000000
    [landDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [area] => 5.09
            [frontage] => 0
        )
    [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [display] => yes
                    [streetview] => yes
                )
            [streetNumber] => 123
            [street] => Smith St
            [suburb] => My Suburb
            [state] => My State
            [postcode] => 1234
        )
    [category] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => House
                )

        )

)

As you can see, the attributes are not returned in the object for the the elements "price", "landDetails->area" and "landDetails->frontage".
The attributes of other elements are returned correctly.
Can anyone tell me why these attributes are not included in the SimpleXMLElement Object and how to access them.
Thanks so much

You can not rely on dumping an SimpleXMLElement, because it may not be complete.

Don't rely on what print_r() shows. (string)$xml->residential->price->attributes()->display does return yes.

See also comments from documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php
